# Drawing black color border to entire activity

Tags: android

I have an Android activity and I need to draw a black border for the entire activity. My xml file for the activity is -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#33B5E5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to create a xml file in the drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:color="@color/dark" android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

And calling this file as `android:background` in your root view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your_xml">
```

Comment: This answer seems simplest as it involves least overdraw.

Comment: Maybe need to set padding to your root relativelayout to be visible, as you ViewPager is on the top, or put the android:background to the viewpager

Comment: Thank you. I added android:background to viewpager but still the same. How to set padding in root relativelayout

Comment: android:padding="2dp"

Answer (score 1):

Made a background `<layer-list>` drawable. Apply as `android:background` property in your activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:top="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: didi you get the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create **boder.xml** in folder drawble :

> ```
> <stroke
>     android:width="1px"
>     android:color="@android:color/black" />
>
> <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
>
> <padding
>     android:bottom="2dp"
>     android:left="2dp"
>     android:right="2dp"
>     android:top="2dp" />
> ```

Then you set background for RelativeLayout